# Unable to export the IIS result to CSV

Tags: powershell, iis, application-pool

I have created a script to get all the IIS Sites and App-pool details from multiple servers, the script is working fine as expected, but I am unable to export the results to CSV file.

It will helpful if someone suggest on how can I export the output details to CSV file.

**CODE**

```
#Import-Module -Name WebAdministration

$Computers = Get-Content "C:\Desktop\Scripts\Servers.txt"

foreach ($server in $Computers) {

    $iis = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'IISADMIN'" -ComputerName $server

    if ($iis.State -eq 'Running') 
    { 
    $details = Write-Host "IIS is running on $server" -ForegroundColor Green 
    #Chandu
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers -ScriptBlock {
    # Changed to newer IISAdministration Module to match Get-IISAppPool
    $Websites = Get-IISSite

    foreach ($Website in $Websites) {

        $AppPool = Get-IISAppPool -Name $Website.Applications[0].ApplicationPoolName
        #$Website.ApplicationPool
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Server_Name = $env:COMPUTERNAME +'.'+ $env:USERDNSDOMAIN
            Website_Name                  = $Website.Name
            Website_Id                    = $Website.Id -join ';'
            Website_State                 = $Website.State -join ';'
            Website_PhysicalPath          = $Website.PhysicalPath -join ';'
            Website_Bindings              = $Website.Bindings.Collection -join ';'
            Website_Attributes            = ($Website.Attributes | ForEach-Object { $_.name + "=" + $_.value }) -join ';'
            AppPool_Name                  = $AppPool.Name -join';'
            AppPool_State                 = $AppPool.State -join ';'
            AppPool_ManagedRuntimeVersion = $AppPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion -join ';'
            AppPool_ManagedPipelineMode   = $AppPool.ManagedPipelineMode -join ';'
            AppPool_StartMode             = $AppPool.StartMode -join ';'
          }
        } Export-csv -Path "C:\Desktop\Scripts\IISite_App-pool_Details.csv" -Append
      }    
   }
} 
#Export-Excel -Append -Path C:\Desktop\Scripts\IISite_App-pool_Details.xlsx -AutoSize -BoldTopRow
```

Comment: Assign the output of your loops in a variable and pipe this to `Export-Csv` afterwards.

Comment: @Olaf I didnt get that, can you please help me with some code.

Comment: You add a variable assignment in front of your foreach loop `$Result = foreach ($server in $Computers) { ......... }` ... and later you pipe that to Export-Csv `$Result | Export-Csv ..... `  ... and of course you remove the Export-Csv from inside your loops

Comment: ```$output = foreach($website in $websites){ 
    ...............}

$output | Export-csv -Path "C:\Desktop\Scripts\IISite_App-pool_Details.csv" -Append ```

Comment: When i exported in my output i am not getting the date for Website_PhysicalPath Website_Bindings and in extra I am getting some coloums as PSComputerName RunspaceId PSShowComputerName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add switch `-HideComputerName` to the `Invoke-Command` cal, but then still the output will also have properties 'RunspaceId' and 'PSShowComputerName' added to it.

If you don't want those, you can de-select them from the result like

```
$iis = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'IISADMIN'" -ComputerName $server

if ($iis.State -eq 'Running') { 
    $details = Write-Host "IIS is running on $server" -ForegroundColor Green 
    #Chandu
    $result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers -ScriptBlock {
        # Changed to newer IISAdministration Module to match Get-IISAppPool
        $Websites = Get-IISSite

        foreach ($Website in $Websites) {
            $AppPool = Get-IISAppPool -Name $Website.Applications[0].ApplicationPoolName
            #$Website.ApplicationPool
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Server_Name                   = $env:COMPUTERNAME +'.'+ $env:USERDNSDOMAIN
                Website_Name                  = $Website.Name
                Website_Id                    = $Website.Id -join ';'
                Website_State                 = $Website.State -join ';'
                Website_PhysicalPath          = $Website.Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath -join ';'
                Website_Bindings              = (Get-Website -Name $Website.Name).bindings.Collection join ';'
                Website_Attributes            = ($Website.Attributes | ForEach-Object { $_.name + "=" + $_.value }) -join ';'
                AppPool_Name                  = $AppPool.Name -join';'
                AppPool_State                 = $AppPool.State -join ';'
                AppPool_ManagedRuntimeVersion = $AppPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion -join ';'
                AppPool_ManagedPipelineMode   = $AppPool.ManagedPipelineMode -join ';'
                AppPool_StartMode             = $AppPool.StartMode -join ';'
            }
        } 
    }
    # remove the extra properties Invoke-Command added
    $result = $result | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty 'PSComputerName','RunspaceId','PSShowComputerName'
    # save the result as CSV file
    $result | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Desktop\Scripts\IISite_App-pool_Details.csv" -NoTypeInformation        
}
```

P.S. Your code doesn't show where you initialized variable `$Computers`..

Comment: The above script gave me the right output but why am I not able to get the Website_PhysicalPath Website_Bindings in the output file

Comment: @nikonD3400 Oh, sorry, I thought your question was about how to export the data because of _" the script is working fine as expected, but I am unable to export the results to CSV file."_ From what I could find, I think you need `(Get-WebSite $Website.Name).PhysicalPath`, but I also saw `$Website.Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath`. Cannot test this myself though. As for the Bindings, have a look at [Get-IISSiteBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/get-iissitebinding?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

Comment: I am not sure how to put that in the script to get the details for bindings and Physical path

Comment: @nikonD3400 Well, again, I cannot test this myself, but I gather you ca try `Website_PhysicalPath = $Website.Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath -join ';'` and ``Website_Bindings= (Get-IISSiteBinding $Website.Name).bindingInformation  -join ';'``

Comment: Physical path is working but for Binding I am getting the below error `The term 'Get-IISSiteBinding' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,  script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was  included, verify that the path is correct and try again.     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-IISSiteBinding:String) [], Command     NotFoundException     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException     + PSComputerName        : server.com`

Comment: @nikonD3400 then how about `Website_Bindings = (Get-Website -Name $Website.Name).bindings.Collection join ';'
`

Comment: now i am getting the details for the Bindings as well, thanks for your help

Comment: @nikonD3400 Thanks for testing it all out. I have updated my answer with the code you verified.